# Pass only ID name of object without quotes

Tags: javascript

in this code bellow I pass the object  using only your id name without '"' and the "console.log()" show me the object . I really thought he will return a error. Someone can explain it to me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 

<a href="#" id='teste'>Test Link</a>

<p id="demo" onclick='myFunction(teste)'>Click Me</p>

<script>
function myFunction(teste) {
    console.log(teste);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting!  you're getting the element from the window object.  Every element with an id is automatically added into the window object, so your passing the element which `id === 'teste'`.

Comment: then, it will works in any browsers? (I see you IE)

Comment: See the dupe question!